# How to run Multiple command in GCP remote builder

Tags: google-cloud-build

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/remote-builder
  waitFor: ["-"]
  env:
    # Use Container Optimized OS
    # https://cloud.google.com/container-optimized-os/docs/
    - INSTANCE_ARGS=--image-project cos-cloud --image-family cos-stable
    - ZONE=us-central1-f
    - USERNAME=cloud-user
    # Run a script from the local build context in a Docker container
    - COMMAND=docker run -v /home/cloud-user/workspace:/workspace ubuntu:16.04 bash -xe /workspace/test-scripts/no-op.sh
```

I want to use multiple commands in above given example

Comment: Hi, does [Multiple commands in the same build step in Google Cloud Builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55863128/multiple-commands-in-the-same-build-step-in-google-cloud-builder) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks i will try that

Comment: Cool, keep me posted.

Comment: Use the answer with the entrypoint, and you can use you own custom builder, not only ubuntu!